# I get null as result in useSelector from react redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, redux-toolkit

In Component useSelector return null. Why? I read data from cloud firestore.

```
const products = useSelector((state) => state.products.products);
console.log(products) - this is null, why?
```

productSlice.js

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you don't need need the `if (state.loadingProducts === true)` condition. Because anyway fulfilled state is happening after pending state.

Comment: No, I delete if condition, and still is null.

Comment: And If I change something in component where I call `const products = useSelector((state) => state.products.products);` and save, and not refresh page, products are not null

Comment: can you add your store file and also would be much better for debug purpose if you share a sandbox as this implies at 3 files

Comment: by the way if you have only one argument for the arrow function you don't need () --> const products = useSelector( state => state.products.products);

Comment: Also from screen you have shared seems there are either some eslint error or some engine one as those trailing underscore red lines

Comment: @JelenaAjdukovic did you find a solution for your problem ? I'm facing the same one!